# jquery not redirecting page with AJX URL result

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

I am using the Paypal API, this was all working fine a year ago then the project was put on hold, last year it was working via http I have changes this to https. The returning json object was stripped and the page went to the paypay url, to complete the transaction. Now nothing fires.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/checkout123.php',
    data: {my_json_data: json}, 
    type: 'POST',
    //async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        if (data.goto) location=data.goto;
    }
});
```

and the response:

```
www.hullsantarun.org{"goto":"https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/cgi-bin\/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-3W625739PV925654X"}
```

I believe this should redirect, the url is valid when I copy into a browser.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can u check this for redirection

```
 location.href=data.goto 
 OR
 window.location.href=data.goto
```